# Alamofire: How to download files sequentially

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an array of video files that I want to download. I am using a for loop to download each of them. However when the loop runs, all the files download in parallel, which causes the app to hang, the UI to freeze, CPU use to go through the roof.

```
for url in urlArray{
  downloadfile(url)
}
```

I have a function that downloads the file given a URL.

```
func downloadFile(s3Url:String)->Void{ 
    Alamofire.download(.GET, s3Url, destination: destination)
         .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
             println(totalBytesRead)
         }
         .response { request, response, _, error in
             println(response)
         }
}
```

How can I change this so the files dont all download at the sametime? Also, how can I check that a download is finished so I can update my UI?

Comment: @mattt would you be able to provide an example? I tried wrapping downloadFile in a NSBlockOperation but it didnt work. ie:             let operation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
                println("starting download")
                self.downloadfile(url!)
            }
            
            queue.addOperation(operation)

Comment: That should be all there is to it. What's not working?

Comment: @mattt it still downloads them all at the same time. I give up now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is call out to another function when a file completes downloading (i.e. totalBytesRead >= totalBytesExpectedToRead). In that function, pop the next item off your list and call the download function again with the new URL. You could make an array of all the URLs and when you need a new item, remove it from the array and pass it to the download function. Check if the array is empty and if it is, you know you are done downloading everything.

The reason you can't just use a loop as you have is that Alamofire requests are always asynchronous so after the request is made, control returns immediately and your program continues before any data is downloaded.

Answer (score 14):

```
func downloadFile(var urlArray:[String])->Void{
    if let s3Url = urlArray.popLast(){
        Alamofire.download(.GET, s3Url, destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                println(totalBytesRead)
            }
            .response { request, response, _, error in
                downloadFile(urlArray)
                println(response)
        }
    }
}
```

swift 3.0:

```
func downloadFile(urlArray:[String])->Void{
    var urlArray = urlArray
    if let s3Url = urlArray.popLast(){
        Alamofire.download(.GET, s3Url, destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                println(totalBytesRead)
            }
            .response { request, response, _, error in
                downloadFile(urlArray)
                println(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A function that calls itself is something that makes me a little 'fear, but it works as expected. (made like this, the world should not explode...)

Comment: sadly `var` will be removed in **Swift 3**. How can we change these code?

Comment: where did you hear var is being removed?

Comment: Is it working in the meanwhile to switch one controller to another , i mean to say in background?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help.

```
var urlArray:[String] =["your file link","your file link"] 

func downloadFile(url: String)->Void{

        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

        Alamofire.download(
            url,
            method: .get,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //progress closure

            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                //result closure
                self.urlArray.removeFirst()
                if DefaultDownloadResponse.response?.statusCode == 200 {

                    print(DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL)

                    if !self.urlArray.isEmpty{
                            self.downloadFile(url: self.urlArray[0])
                    }
                }

            })
}
```